# TSQL - Return Boolean result in select query

Tags: sql, sql-server

SQL Server does not seem to support selecting Boolean result.
Example:

```
Select True;
```

Or

```
Select 1>2;
```

would return an Error.
However, in the majority of programming languages a similar operation is valid. Is there a reason for that?

Comment: Because SQL isn't a programming language. It's a Query language.

Comment: _Select True_ could be written as `SELECT Convert(bit, 1)`. _Select 1>2_ could be written as `SELECT CASE WHEN x = y THEN Convert(bit, 1) ELSE Convert(bit, 0) END`

Comment: Just to mention, you can use the bit datatype to represent boolean data. It can hold either 1,0 or null

Comment: Because boolean types are not included in the standard and were not deemed necessary for a language whose focus is on *sets*.

Answer (score 3):

SQL is not designed for deductive statements. however you can achieve similar results using a statement like this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN 2 > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```